# Reset Chinese Input Method candidate word frequency records?

Tags: keyboard, keybindings, macos

This issue happens for all macOS 10.x. For Chinese input methods like Sucheng, it has a feature that can "Adjust word frequency" according to the frequency of usage of each word.

When I disabled the "Adjust word frequency", the word order remains the same, but no longer changes according to the frequency of usage.

How can I reset the word usage count to zero? I tried to remove and re-add the input method, the word frequency remains the same.

Comment: Please don't cross-post to multiple SE sites. Pick one & stick to it, or flag for migration. 
[Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/) - https://superuser.com/questions/1701155/reset-chinese-input-method-candidate-word-frequency-records-in-macos-x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the problem, I finally tracked down the dictionary which controls the frequency of words:

```
~/Library/Dictionaries/DynamicPhraseLexicon_yue_Hant_Sucheng.db
```

Remove this file as well as the `yue_Hant-dynamic.lm` folder, and then log out & re-login. The frequency will be reset.

Alternatively, as this file is a SQLite DB file, you can use DB editor to reset the count in the database. There is only 1 table `Assist` in the file, which contains `Identifier`, `LastSeedValue`, `LastUpdateTime` and `Version`.

Note: you can substitute the `Sucheng` for other Chinese input method names.